# awk: fatal: cannot open file ' for reading (No such file or directory)

Tags: shell, awk

I have a directory which contains a lot of files with .sum extension.
I used the below script to list the contents of all the .sum files to a temp.log file. While the first .sum file gets written to temp.log the awk utility seems to give error for the remaining .sum files. Please help, what i am missing in here.

```
cd $HOME/aphp/result/${test}



for filename in *.sum
do
tempdir=$filename
awk '/Failed/' "${filename}" > temp.log
awk '/Error/'  "${filename}" >> temp.log
    if [ -s temp.log ]
    then        

    mkdir -p ${scanresult}/${tempdir}
    mv temp.log ${scanresult}/${tempdir}/temp.log
    cd ${scanresult}/${tempdir}
    mv temp.log ${tempdir}_failed.txt
    else
    echo Skipping ${tempdir} scanning as it is executed 100 percent with no fail or error.
    rm temp.log      
    fi
done
```

Errors:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `dss154.sum' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `dss235.sum' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `dss287.sum' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

ls -l *.sum

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 smruti smruti 1844 Mar 25 16:23 dss103.sum
-rwxrwxrwx 1 smruti smruti 2353 Mar 25 16:40 dss154.sum
-rwxrwxrwx 1 smruti smruti 1023 Mar 25 16:43 dss235.sum
-rwxrwxrwx 1 smruti smruti  908 Mar 25 16:45 dss287.sum
-rwxrwxrwx 1 smruti smruti  867 Mar 25 16:45 dss288.sum
-rwxrwxrwx 1 smruti smruti 1064 Mar 25 16:47 dss350.sum
```

Comment: Show output of `ls -l *.sum`

Comment: Does every file in the current directory give you that error? What are the permissions on the files?

Comment: All files have read permission and i am executing as a Super user. Only the first file gets read by awk, the remaining file are skipped with error.

Comment: @Smruti: Don't place output in comments. Edit your question and provide it there.

Comment: the dss103.sum file gets read and the line with 'failed' word gets logged in temp file.

Comment: Are the other files opened exclusively by other processes? Can you show output of `fuser *.sum`?

Comment: @alvits fuser *.sum does not give any output. I wonder ... if it is failing it should fail for all the files. But it reads the first file and then fails for the rest.

Comment: Is this the complete loop or you removed some steps inside the loop? Can you test if the sendfile is at least readable? If the secondfile is readable can you test `ls *.sum|xargs awk '/Failed/' >> tepm.log`? If the issue is indeed file access, then you should see the same exact error message.

Comment: @alvits: I checked again .. the file doesnot have a read access. I believe it is something to do with the awk statement inside the for loop.

Comment: There is your problem, `cd`. You `cd`ed to another directory and never went back to the original directory. to process the succeeding files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting into this problem due to this line:

```
cd ${scanresult}/${tempdir}
```

Which is changing your current working directory to something else. After which rest of the files cannot be read after 1st file. It is not really clear why are you changing directory inside the loop.

You can use this line to go back to original path:

```
cd -
```

However most of your code after awk command looks suspicious and redundant.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. fixed it and it works .. Thanks a ton again... And yes.. removed most of the redundant codes...